# GLM & LM assumptions and interpretation

Tags: r, glm, lm, lme4

I am currently running some linear models and lmer (with replicate as a random effect) for continuous data and a glm and glmer (again, replicate as a random effect) for count data.

I was wondering if a lm, lmer, glm and glmer all need the data to be normally distributed and if not, do I need an alternative test?

Also, I have run a glm and looked at the pairwise differences and when reporting it other than P<0.001 I don't know what else I should report! As my glm output doesn't really give me that much. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Also have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Confirming with Christoph, CrossValidated is the best site for statistical modelling questions on SE.